# Como serializar e deserializar JSON em VB?

Tags: visual-basic-6

Estou tentando serializar e deserializar JSON em VB, mas não estou conseguindo o único código de achei de deserializar não está funcionando

---

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim uriString As String = "https://api.github.com/users/VitorHugoFra"
        Dim uri As New Uri(uriString)

        Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(uri), HttpWebRequest)
        Request.Method = "GET"

        Dim Response As WebResponse = Request.GetResponse()

        Dim Read = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim Raw As String = Read.ReadToEnd()
        Dim dict As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of List(Of (Object, ))(Raw)


        For Each item As Object In dict
            TextBox1.Text += item("login").ToString + "-" + item("location").ToString + vbNewLine
        Next
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Encontrei duas bibliotecas, A VB-JSON: http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html e a Chilkat: https://www.example-code.com/vb6/json.asp. A segunda inclusive tem vários exemplos. Verifique se alguma serve para você.

Comment: A tag da pergunda está exibindo visual-basic-6 (11/2022), mas creio ser VB.Net, confere?